# ¿Cómo interpreta R este tipo de subconjuto? (Ver ejemplo)

Tags: r, funciones

Reviso algunos videos y materiales para refrescar mis ideas sobre funciones y encontré un ejemplo similar a este:

Primero una base de datos super sencilla:

```
data <- data.frame(peli=c("Perro", "Gato", "Niño"), promedio=c(9, 7.1, 3),
    edades= c("11", "15,"18"))
```

Después una función que nos diga si la valoración es "Sí" o "No" dependiendo del número ingresado

```
rating_val <- function(x) {
    if(x < 7) {
    return("No")
    }else{
    return("Sí")
    }
    }
```

Finalmente, una función en la que incluimos la función creada previamente. A esta función le ingresamos un nombre y nos regresa un "Sí" o "No":

```
valor_peli <- function(name) {
    rating <- data[data[,1]==name, "promedio"]
    valor <- rating_val(rating)
    return(valor)
    }

valor_peli("Perro") ##Regresa "Sí"
```

Mi duda está en la asignación a rating dentro de la función "valor_peli", ya que cuando hacemos:

```
data[data[,1]]
```

Nos regresa la base de datos completa.

Y cuando hacemos:

```
data[data[,1], "promedio"]
```

Nos regresa los valores de la variable "promedio".

En consecuencia, no me queda claro cómo es que rating "aisla" el nombre de la primera columna y nos regresa finalmente "Sí" o "No".

Lo anterior me causa aún más conflicto ya que por ejemplo, los datos en edades están codificados como caracteres, así que en teoría deberíamos obtener también el promedio asignado para ese nombre. Sin embargo:

```
valor_peli("11")
Error in if (x < 7) { : argumento tiene longitud cero
```

Espero que mi duda haya quedado clara. Aprecio mucho cualquier orientación al respecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veamos, tenemos este `data.frame`:

```
> data
   peli promedio edades
1 Perro      9.0     11
2  Gato      7.1     15
3  Niño      3.0     18
```

Cuando haces `data[data[,1]]`, básicamente lo que está haciendo es lo siguiente:

```
data[,as.numeric(data[,1])]
```

Es decir:

- En primer lugar, si no indexas por fila y columna (es decir no usas la coma para separar ambos valores), la selección aplicará a las columnas (no a las filas)
- Luego, como `data[,1]` es decir `promedio` es un `factor` esto se coerciona a un numérico, como hacer `as.numeric(data[,1])` -> `[1] 3 1 2`, por lo que lo único que logras es cambiar el orden de las columnas, en este caso que tienes igual cantidad de filas que de columnas, si tuvieras más filas, terminarías con un `data.frame` con columnas repetidas.

Ejemplo:

```
> data[data[,1]]
  edades  peli promedio
1     11 Perro      9.0
2     15  Gato      7.1
3     18  Niño      3.0
```

Puedes notar que las columnas han cambiado de orden respetando los valores del `factor` (que está ordenado alfabéticamente) es decir `[1] 3 1 2`. Ahora bien, los `Factores` en el contexto de un filtro y agregando la selección de la columna:

```
> data[data[,1]=="Perro", "promedio"]
[1] 9
> data[data[,1]=="Gato", "promedio"]
[1] 7.1
```

funcionarán bien, con una particularidad que es importante hacer notar en este caso: Por defecto R "promociona" el resultado final a uno más primitivo si se puede. En este caso como solo estas recuperando una única columna el resultado final será un `vector`, un ejemplo sería el siguiente:

```
# Se retorna un vector por defecto
> data[, "promedio"]
[1] 9.0 7.1 3.0
# al usar drop=FALSE se mantiene la clase del objeto
> data[, "promedio", drop=FALSE]
  promedio
1      9.0
2      7.1
3      3.0
```

En cuanto a tu otra duda, ten en cuenta que cuando haces `valor_peli("11")` en definitiva, esta filtrando los registros dónde `peli == "11"`, es decir, no hay casos, por consiguiente el error posterior.

Por último, en `rating_val`  estás usando un `if` común que no está vectorizado, lo que te añade una restricción en esta función: no puede recibir más de un único valor, tal vez no sea tu idea, pero puedes hacer algo más flexible la lógica usando `ifelse()` así:

```
valor_peli <- function(name) {
    ifelse(data[data$peli==name,"promedio"]>7, "Si", "No")
}
```

Comment: Genial tu explicación. Me quedó muy claro todo. ¡Muchas gracias!